# Mac OSX Server - AFP Firewalling

Tags: afp

Is it possible to write an ipfw rule to:

1 - block a specific AFP Share by the Shares Name?

2 - block that AFP Share from access by anyone but the local network, i.e: no external IPs.

And if so could I have an example please based on my AFP Share name of 'CLOUD'
Thx.

MacPro OSX Server 10.7.latest

Netgear SRX5308

Comment: I found this for you: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6145077

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no... the relevant ipfw rules are all IP/portnumber based and are completely ignorant of protocol specific info like share names.... this means you can either allow all or nothing for the AFP service on the server.

Obviously, if you have 2 servers, just kill outside access for that one server, but then you probably wouldn't be asking the question.

A workaround hack would be to fire up a VM on the server that gets a totally different IP address and then use ipfw to allow/deny as appropriate.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: Thank you.
Best thing I think will be to stop them using a shared login [:-O] and make everyone have separate user accounts [:-)] and do the right thing from there on...
I can hear their screaming now... hello OD √√
Kind regards :-)

Comment: Ooof, yes.  Gentle reminder to mark the question as answered!